# Corpus from TextMining requires explicit parent type conversion

Tags: julia, text-mining

I am experimenting with Julia's [text mining module](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/TextAnalysis.jl/tree/7377ea933e97622fe95188de5cf600fb94f8fa0b).

When I feed the `Corpus` function with a `DataArray{TextAnalysis.StringDocument,1}` I got a convert error, i.e. (note I am using the `Lazy`pacakge to pipeline commands)

```
using Lazy, TextMining, DataArrays

@>> @data(["hello","bro"]) map(StringDocument) Corpus

->LoadError: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{TextAnalysis.Corpus}, ::DataArrays.DataArray{TextAnalysis.StringDocument,1})
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor TextAnalysis.Corpus(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.WARNING: Error showing method candidates, aborted
```

I need to apply `convert(Vector{GenericDocument})` to have this piece of code work:

```
@>> @data(["hello","bro"]) map(StringDocument) convert(Vector{GenericDocument}) Corpus
```

Here's the [Corpus](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/TextAnalysis.jl/blob/7377ea933e97622fe95188de5cf600fb94f8fa0b/src/corpus.jl) function:

```
type Corpus
    documents::Vector{GenericDocument}
    total_terms::Int
    lexicon::Dict{Compat.UTF8String, Int}
    inverse_index::Dict{Compat.UTF8String, Vector{Int}}
    h::TextHashFunction
end

function Corpus(docs::Vector{GenericDocument})
    Corpus(
        docs,
        0,
        Dict{Compat.UTF8String, Int}(),
        Dict{Compat.UTF8String, Vector{Int}}(),
        TextHashFunction()
    )
end

Corpus(docs::Vector{Any}) = Corpus(convert(Array{GenericDocument,1}, docs))
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You seems to be using a Pipelining package (Lazy.jl?) please either remove the pipeline syntax (to focus your question). Or at very least including `using Lazy`  (or which ever module it is) so your code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code.

1. `@data` creates a DataArray, which TextAnalysis code does not know what to do with. Writing an explicit convert, as you do, is a perfectly acceptable way to handle this. Is there a particular reason you are using DataArrays, rather than plain arrays?
2. Even if you remove `@data`, the code will fail currently. That is because the constructor of `Corpus` is limited in what it can take as parameters (and the fact that Julia arrays are not co-variant).

One workaround, again is to explicitly convert. A proper fix will be to define the a new constructor as below. This should probably be added to the package, but you can use the following code in your REPL directly:

```
TextAnalysis.Corpus{T<:AbstractDocument}(docs::Vector{T}) = TextAnalysis.Corpus(convert(Array{GenericDocument,1}, docs))
```

with this, you can do:

```
julia> @>> ["hello","bro"] map(StringDocument) Corpus
A Corpus
```